# Socket.io loading very slow

Tags: node.js, sockets

First time then i run web server my main page loading about 25 s and then i remove this line:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>` my page is working fine. So why socket.io is so slow ?

```
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
io.set('log level', 1);                    // reduce logging
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Comment: This is a good question and I have experienced the same thing. As soon as I comment out socketio related code in nodejs, I no longer experience the 20 second start up time. Would love to know if there is an easy fix for this.